# Are there some better approaches to convert a byte array of pdf with PdfStripper?

Tags: java, pdf, text, pdfbox

I have got a byte array of a pdf file and want to get the text out of the file. My code below works, but I need to create an actual file first. Do you know a better way, so I don't have to create this file first?

```
try {
  File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-pdf", ".tmp");
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
  out.write(Base64.decodeBase64(testObject.getPdfAsDoc().getContent()));
  out.close();
  PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(temp);
  PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
  String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
  log.info(text);
} catch(IOException e){

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on the version of PDFBox you use.

#### PDFBox 2.0.x

Whenever you have a `byte[]` (you appear to get one from `Base64.decodeBase64`), you can load it directly:

```
byte[] documentBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(testObject.getPdfAsDoc().getContent());
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(documentBytes);
```

#### PDFBox 1.8.x

Whenever you have a `byte[]`, you can load it via a `ByteArrayInputStream`:

```
byte[] documentBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(testObject.getPdfAsDoc().getContent());
InputStream documentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(documentBytes);
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(documentStream);
```

As an aside: When working with PDFBox 1.8.x you should use a `loadNonSeq` overload instead of `load` because `load` does not load a PDF as it is specified and, therefore, can be fooled to read it with wrong contents. In case of broken PDFs, though, you may still try `load` as fallback.

Comment: With the recent updates loadNonSeq seems to be no more available in PDDocument (although it's not explicitely mentioned in 
 https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html)

Comment: The use of `loadNonSeq` is recommended only for PDFBox 1.8.x. The PDFBox 2 `load` is the former PDFBox 1.8.x `loadNonSeq`.